# iframe height adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Is there a way to set the height of the iframe to be the same as the height of its source?

I am trying to
a) Avoid scrollbars and
b) Avoid using fixed height in px

Thank you. :)

Comment: The "height of its source" meaning the height of the page displayed inside the frame?

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning indeed. Also, the source page is on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since the source page is on a different domain — no.

The only way to adjust its size based on the content is to measure the rendered size of the content using JavaScript, and the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you have control over the iframe-content? in that case i wrote [a javascript thingie (squeezeFrame.js)](http://futtta.be/squeezeFrame/) a couple of weeks ago, that can do just what you need.

essentially it uses;

- [clientWidth](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#elementview) (and optionally -Height) to get the size of the "viewport"
- scrollWidth (again optionally -Height) to get the size of the entire (iframed) page
- zoom (and -moz-transform: scale for firefox) to zoom in/out

you can see [a couple of demo's of squeezeFrame.js in action here](http://futtta.be/squeezeFrame/)

Comment: No, no control over the content inside the iframe, unfortunately. Thank you for your contribution, it could be useful in other situations than mine, and it is good to know!